# Using VPATH with ndk-build

Tags: android-ndk, makefile, vpath

Currently trying to port a `Makefile` to an `Android.mk` file such that I can build a shared library with `ndk-build`

I can't seem to get VPATH to do anything though.

e.g.

```
# File: Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := example

MY_API_SRCS = \
    core/src/destroy.c \
    core/src/initialise.c \
    core/src/loadLibrary.c \
    core/src/loadSettings.c \
    core/src/processPulses.c
```

works fine, but trying to strip out the directory part and specify a VPATH instead doesn't, e.g.

```
# File: Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := example

VPATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/core/src

MY_API_SRCS = \
    destroy.c \
    initialise.c \
    loadLibrary.c \
    loadSettings.c \
    processPulses.c
```

I get a `no such file or directory error` when running `ndk-build`

Am I right in thinking you should be able to use standard GNU Make syntax in an Android.mk file? Not sure why this isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

You have a backslash there on your VPATH :p

Comment: You forgot to add your VPATH into your include directory. Add this line: LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += YOUR_VPATH_HERE

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either - surely that is for header files not anything related to VPATH?

Comment: ..and of course, you should have this LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MY_API_SRC also, on top of your VPATH, also add this $(LOCAL_PATH) and $(JNI_H_INCLUDE)